# How to prevent DIV wrapping if they don't have a fixed size?

Tags: html, css, width

I'm completely pissed off with the divs, I'm soon to be done with website, but a simple thing I have no idea how to solve.

Basically I got a menu and a content `div`s, the content is different from page to page and I don't want them to wrap against each other.

I've read dozens of posts saying exactly to put a min-width to a wrapper, but I've no idea what my min-width would be. Some pages are just 600px width, while some are almost 1000px, Its got to be used as a PHP template.

Here is the code, I'll be very glad if some one can help at all, because I'm completely frustrated with this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div {
      padding: 2px
    }
    
    div.menu {
      background-color: #FAFAA0;
      float: left;
    }
    
    div.content {
      background-color: #9DFBA9;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    The pages which have different size here. For example:
    <div style="width:600px">Page one</div>
    or
    <div style="width:900px">Page two?</div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both">
    In either way I dont wan't this two divs wrapping, but I don't know the exact size of the content page.<br> So I can't just put a min width like 1024px.<br> When they are about to wrap, the scrollbar should appear only then...<br> How can I achieve
    that?
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What layout are you trying to accomplish? Floating all of the `div`s shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: The layout is very simple, its just this:

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/21663387.png/
I use 4 divs, header, menu, content and footer, but if the content is too big, it gets under the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after? http://jsbin.com/exuvoz

I enclosed the `.menu` and `.content` elements in a `<div>` with `float: left`, and [changed](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats) `div.content { float: left; }` to `div.content { overflow: hidden; }`.

Comment: Thanks, well it kind of ... works *** but it gets my content chopped... :( So it's not what I'm looking.
The thing is I don't want the hidden overflow, the page might be just long, and it must be visible, but if its not getting fit, then the scrollbar should appear.

Comment: What browser are you using that chops the content?! `overflow: hidden` shouldn't be doing that here, unless there's something else on your actual page causing it. Anyway, you can replace `overflow: hidden` with `margin-left: <width of your menu>px`, like this: http://jsbin.com/exuvoz/2

Comment: Thanks, well I'm using IE an Google chrome, both show chop...:  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/406/getschopped.png/
I will try it with margin right now.

Comment: I'm still testing with margin. It seems we're getting really close, the content is fixed, some of it stays right where it should be and reacts as intent on resize. Some of the content though still gets below the level of the menu, though it stays so even upon resize.
I think its probably due to the fact that the are some other divs inside the content that are using float: left and clear:both respectedly. I am into investigating this.

Comment: Hell yes, it seems to work finally!
I've used the margin as you've told me.
Then I've had to add another div wrapper with float left inside the content div. So now the other divs that were in the content div do neither cause the wrapping.
Thanks very much for your help!! :-) <3 !

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in Chrome, IE9 and Firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {padding:2px}
div.wrapper { display: table; }
div.menu{
    background-color:#FAFAA0;
    display: table-cell;  
    }
div.content{
    background-color:#9DFBA9;
    display: table-cell;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu"> 
      menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    The pages which have different size here. For example:
    <div style="width:600px">Page one</div>
    or
    <div style="width:900px">Page two?</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both">
In either way I dont wan't this two divs wrapping, but I don't know the exact size of the content page.<br>
So I can't just put a min width like 1024px.<br>
When they are about to wrap, the scrollbar should appear only then...<br>
How can I achieve that?
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you will laugh, by now the menu jumps down for some reason...
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/641/menujumpsdown.png/
On some other pages the menu stays up, but then the content jumps down likewise :O

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {padding:2px}
div.menu{
    background-color:#FAFAA0;
    float:left;
    }
div.content{
    background-color:#9DFBA9;
    float:left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="min-width:600px;border:1px solid;">
<div class="menu" style="width:10%"> 
    menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu
</div>
<div class="content" style="width:80%">
    The pages which have different size here. For example:
    <div style="">Page one</div>
    or
    <div style="">Page two?</div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both">
In either way I dont wan't this two divs wrapping, but I don't know the exact size of the content page.<br>
So I can't just put a min width like 1024px.<br>
When they are about to wrap, the scrollbar should appear only then...<br>
How can I achieve that?
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So what happened actually is I put your menus div and content div into one div. Please look closely on the inline styles that I placed. And instead of using "px" use percentage. Hope this helps.

Comment: So using percentage here will adopt to the size of the parent div or your main wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, well I've just tried this. On some pages with it gets a scrollbar and I am able to scroll it a little, but if I resize a little more, it then jumps down under the menu as before.
On some other pages - they just jump down under the menu like before.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try display:table on wrapper and display:table-cell on menu and content?

Comment: I did sort of try them, but it didn't work for me. I have no idea how to apply them though, because I never used them before. If you could modify my code and attach these tags, I would test it again right away. Or just tell precisely where to put them... Thanks

Comment: Put your menu and content in a wrapper div with display:table style and set display:table-cell on menu and content. I can not do it for you right now as i have iphone only with me :-)